# karma sonarqube unit reporter output comes out as HTML

Tags: sonarqube, karma-runner, karma-coverage

The coverage output of karma sonarqube unit report comes out as html instead of a xml

I am trying to integrate code coverage during my sonar analysis.

I have have coverageify in my stack, i don't know if it is interfering with my output from sonarqube-unit-reporter. In my karma options, i have it do output an ut_report.xml as suggested in the example its github page.

Here is relevant part of my karma config:

```
        reporters: ['progress', 'sonarqubeUnit', 'coverage'],

        coverageReporter: {
            dir: 'test-coverage/',
            reporters: [
                { type: 'html', subdir: 'html'},
                { type: 'cobertura', subdir: 'reports/app', file: 'coverage.xml' },
                {
                    type : 'lcov',
                    subdir : 'coverage',
                    file: 'sonar.xml'
                }
            ]
        },

        sonarQubeUnitReporter: {
            sonarQubeVersion: '7.6.0',
            outputFile: 'reports/ut_report.xml',
            useBrowserName: false
        },

        plugins: [
            'karma-browserify',
            'karma-mocha',
            'karma-spec-reporter',
            'karma-phantomjs-launcher',
            'karma-coverage',
            'karma-sonarqube-unit-reporter'
        ],
```

But the ut_report.xml is nowhere to be found.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what am I doing differently now but, the xml is being written to the proper place. I suppose it was a path configuration mistake.

Comment: Did you manage to tell sonar to use this XML file? Is it on 'sonar.testExecutionReportPaths' (I'm using jenkins btw).